# Auto click a button that loads immediately a page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a button that displays random number in a textbox and I want it to autoclick once a page is loaded without any delay.How can I do that? I have used this code for textbox and the button.

```
<input id="random-number" value="" />
```

Create Random Number

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Please include details as to what have you do so far to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if you want the random number to be populated when the page loads you could use window.onload instead of trying to auto click the button:  `window.onload = function() {
  generateNumber();
};`

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `click()` method of the button.

`document.getElementById('myButton').click()`

```js
function generateNumber(){
  document.getElementById('randomNumber').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
}

document.getElementById('myButton').click()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="randomNumber" />
<button onclick="generateNumber()" id="myButton">generate number</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @hajile78 mentioned, the core of your question is (or should be) how to execute the function behind the button, and not how to click the button, when the page loads. I suggest you define a function to create a random number and run it when the window loads. Here is an example of a script that you could insert in the `<head>` section of your document (or in a separate JavaScript file):

```html
<head>

  <script>
    function createRandomNumber(){
      // some code to create a random number
     };

    window.onload = createRandomNumber();
  </script>
 
</head>
```

As a more secure alternative, you could also use [jQuery's](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) `ready()` method instead of `window.onload`.